# Android media player: "start called in state 0"

Tags: android

I'm trying to get a simple sound to play. The sound plays on the emulator but not on the phone. It says

> start called in state 0

and

> Error (-38,0)

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
MediaPlayer secondSound;
MediaPlayer minuteSound;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    secondSound = new MediaPlayer();
    secondSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.everysecondsound);
    minuteSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.everyminutesound);


    secondSound.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
            player.start();
        }
    });

    minuteSound.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
            player.start();
        }
    });
}
```

Later in the program, the following methods are called:

```
minuteSound.start();
secondSound.start();
```

On the emulator, this works fine even without the .setOnPreparedListener part. The emulator is running API 22, the phone is running API 19. Is there a different way to use the media player in the older APIs?

Answer (score 3):

When you call `MediaPlayer.create()`, that automatically calls `prepare()` for you, as seen in [the source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/media/java/android/media/MediaPlayer.java#855). As per the [state diagram in the MediaPlayer documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html):
[image: State Diagram of MediaPlayer]

This puts you into the Prepared state. At that point, when you call `start()`, you move into the Started state. After playback completes, you'll be in the Playback Completed state. If you'd like to play your sound again, you have to call `create()` again, or call `stop()` and `prepare()` again.

You'll find [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) more appropriate for short tracks you want to play repeatedly.

Comment: The sounds doesn't play at all. Again this is only on my phone with the older API. On the emulator, everything works perfectly. I have a feeling it has something to do with the older API. 

There's also a text to speech engine running in this program and for that I had to write slightly different code to accommodate the older API.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think you have to declare the minute MediaPayer (as you did with the second), this way: minuteSound = new MediaPlayer();
Try this and return. If it doesn't work, maybe you will have to release the MediaPlayer before calling it again.

Comment: @Sentinel please check the answer you think it was helpful to solve your problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the file format for my sound files. They were originally **96000Hz** wave files, I changed them to **44100Hz** MP3 files and then everything worked. I removed the `.setOnPrepareListener` part since it worked without it.